# How to install software packages from FreeBSD 9.1 DVD?

Tags: unix, freebsd

When FreeBSD 9.0 switched to the new installer, I could still manually launch bsdinstall at end of normal installation process to install pre-built packages on DVD, however this way no longer works in FreeBSD 9.1.

FreeBSD manual makes no mention about this topic.

So how do I install the pre-built packages after installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, 9.1 doesn't include pre-built packages, either on disc or via FTP. This isn't a permanent change, but an unfortunate side effect of the recent security incident. Hopefully there will be packages soon. Until then, you can build from source.

One way to work around this might be to use the stable packages. They'll be outdated, but should run fine. This will of course have to be done post install via the network using pkg_add -r. You'd need to set PACKAGESITE:

```
env PACKAGESITE=http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-9-stable/Latest/ pkg_add -r bash
```

for example. These won't be quite as new as release packages would be, but they should be mostly fine. Be sure to install portaudit, run it, and rebuild anything that has security updates.

Steve

Comment: Thank you Steve. Release announcement says "precompiled third-party packages are not available for 9.1-RELEASE" and then DVD has "a collection of pre-built packages aimed at getting a graphical workstation up and running". Not sure if it is intended, or a mistake in document.